# "Opposite" of idempotent operation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, terminology, computer-science, computational-mathematics

What is the adjective given to a mathematical operation/expression on a variable whose new value can only be described in terms of that variable's existing value? Sequential operation?

- Example: i = **i + 1**
- Counter-example: i = 3 + 1

I don't know if what I call a "sequential operation" is semantically opposite to "idempotent" operation/expression but it does seem like it (e.g. the counter-example shown doesn't change value depending on how often you execute it).

**Why I'm asking**
I'm trying to distinguish between functions in my computer program where you need to read the existing value into memory before you can compute the value from those that can be expressed as simple literals. I need to state in my design document that my program must support both cases, and I want to use the mathematically correct term for it. (note it doesn't need to be numerical, it could be string concatenation vs string overwriting).

Comment: Recursive? Implicit?

Comment: Both of those sound correct based on my definitions of those terms and how I've phrased the question. Whether they evoke the intended meaning in my computer program description I'm not so sure. But I will mark the question as correct if you post it as an answer.

Comment: I'm perfectly happy to wait and see if anything more useful comes up in discussion!

Comment: Thanks Josh. It's reassuring to know that it's an interesting question such that the answer is not trivial :)

Comment: In a computer speak, the value *that can be expressed as simple literals* is called constant.

Comment: Ahah, that was so obvious I didn't think of that. That's good enough for the document I'm writing. I'd still be curious to know if there's a mathematical term for it, though I'm beginning to wonder whether the concept of variable assignment is part of mathematics at all.

Comment: One more suggestion I just thought of - absolute value assignment vs relative value assignment.

Comment: This question is confusing.  The final paragraph has nothing, whatsoever, to do with "idempotent".

Comment: Yeah sorry for wasting your time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Idempotent" means that repeating the operation doesn't change the outcome. That doesn't mean that it doesn't do changes. I.e., asignment is idempotent (asign 10 five times in a row, the result will always be 10); increment isn't (doing `i++` once or twice in C gives different results). Perhaps you mean it has no side effects, or is a "pure" function (each time you call it with the same arguments, the value returned is the same)? Note that e.g. $\sin x$ is pure in this sense (each time you ask for $\sin 1$ you'll get the same result), functions like `printf(3)` or `malloc(3)` in C aren't.

Comment: Interesting - 'pure function' is probably the mathematical term I am hovering around without knowing it. The only remaining question is - what would you call the right hand side of a pure function? A pure expression? How would I write this sentence (it's related to database updates): "If you are assigning a pure expression to the cell, call methodA(). If you are assigning an impure expression to the cell, call methodB()"

Comment: I plead ignorance... ask a couple of people into databases, perhaps check at http://DBA.stackexchange.com or http://stackoverflow.com?

Comment: Just to clarify that even "pure function" in a C programming sense might not be what you want, as a pure function is permitted to examine global memory and consequently the result may be different every time you call it, in contrast a "const function" has no effect other than it's result, and may not access global memory, c.f. the GCC manual on function attributes: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html

Comment: Another observation - pure / const functions in C are nullipotent rather than idempotent

Answer (score 15):

I know this question is more than a year old, but for the sake of posterity, the correct term for "the opposite of idempotent" (at least in computer science) is **non-idempotent**.

For example, see section 9.1.2 of [Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1 (RFC 2616)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html):

> 9.1.2 Idempotent Methods
>
> Methods can also have the property of "idempotence" in that (aside
>   from error or expiration issues) the side-effects of N > 0 identical
>   requests is the same as for a single request. The methods GET, HEAD,
>   PUT and DELETE share this property. Also, the methods OPTIONS and
>   TRACE SHOULD NOT have side effects, and so are inherently idempotent.
>
> **However, it is possible that a sequence of several requests is non-
>   idempotent, even if all of the methods executed in that sequence are
>   idempotent.** (A sequence is idempotent if a single execution of the
>   entire sequence always yields a result that is not changed by a
>   reexecution of all, or part, of that sequence.) For example, a
>   sequence is non-idempotent if its result depends on a value that is
>   later modified in the same sequence.
>
> A sequence that never has side effects is idempotent, by definition
>   (provided that no concurrent operations are being executed on the same
>   set of resources).

Emphasis mine.

Answer (score 11):

I feel that you have an invalid idea of **what *idempotent* really means**. It doesn't matter whether the outcome of the operation relates to the current value of a variable. Let me give you some examples:

- $i = 3 + 1$ is surely idempotent, while:
- $i = i + 1$ is surely not. However:
- $i = i + 0$ is idempotent, even though the new value is calculated based on the current value. Same goes for:
- $i = i * 1$, which is also idempotent. However:
- $i = rand(0, 1)$ is non-idempotent, even though it doesn't relate to it's old value.

To sum up, we say that the **operation is idempotent when performing it multiple times yields the exact same result as performing it exactly once**.

Answering the question asked in the subject of this thread, there are two contrasting terms:

- An operation is nullpotent, when performing it any number of times has the same result as performing it zero times.
- An operation is non-idempotent, when performing it multiple times doesn't necessarily yield the same result every time it is performed.

Let me provide another example, expanding upon example RJ Cuthbertson provided. RJ's example shows how HTTP methods work from the perspective of the client of a service. However, let's glimpse into the service's inner model:

- **GET method is nullpotent**. Operation of *getting* a resource is *pure query* and has no impact on the internal model.
- **PUT method is idempotent**. Operation of *putting* a resource allows the user to designate the exact location it should be made available at. Putting the same resource in the same location multiple times yields the same internal state of the system as posting it exactly once.
- **POST method is non-idempotent**. When posting a resource, the server decides the location it should be made available at. Posting the same resource multiple times will make it available at multiple locations.

Mind you, this is just a pure abstraction. The coder might just as well implement any of these methods to do anything he chooses. This is the way we expect it to behave, though.